# For which cobordism theories framed manifolds not bound?

Tags: stable-homotopy, cobordism

If $X$ is a complex and $\xi:X\to BO$ is a map, when is the natural map from the stable stem $\pi_*^S\to \pi_{*}( M\xi)$ injective, where $M\xi$ is the associated Thom spectrum?

For $MO$ or $MU$, this is not true. If $X$ a sphere and $\xi$ is trivial, it is true (since $M\xi$ becomes wedge of a sphere spectrum with a $\dim(X)$ times suspended one). There are various other examples as well.

So, what might be the necessary and sufficient conditions on $X$ and $\xi$ so that it is the case?

(A particular refinement of this question may be when $X$ is a classifying space of a finite group and $\xi$ induced by a representation (I think Gunnar Carlsson in [Equivariant Stable Homotopy and Segal's Burnside Ring Conjecture](https://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/carlsson.pdf)
, Appendix A, uses these type of spectra).)

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: If $\xi$ is trivial, don't you always get a shifted suspension spectrum of $X$ for $M\xi$? So in this case, you want $\pi^s_*\to\pi_*(M\xi)$ to be injective. Thus I guess your "natural map" should have a certain degree ($\dim X$?)?

Comment: Wedging with the sphere spectrum simply shifts the suspension spectrum of $X$.